# what's the hotkey for cleaning log in xcode4

Tags: xcode, console, keyboard-shortcuts, logging

when I debug,I clean the log info **frequently**.

---

Is there any hotkey for that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you mean the console window, its clover-K: <kbd>⌘</kbd>-<kbd>K</kbd> I think.

Answer (score 1):

Yes there is, it is:

<kbd>⌃</kbd>+<kbd>⌥</kbd>+<kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>

Soure: http://www.1729.us/xcode/Xcode%20Shortcuts.pdf

Comment: sorry,this not work in xcode 4

Answer (score 0):

```
   control + option + command + R
```

You can use the above.